# Jetpack Compose - How Do I program this composable to access the "url" in the "list"

Tags: android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-datastore

//I'm having problems trying to get the title text in the KbfPlayScreen.kt to access the "url" in the list that is in the Data.kt on button click.

```
**KbfPlayScreen.kt**


@Composable
fun KbfSermonsView(sermons: List<Sermon>)   {
  Column() {
    sermons.forEach {
        SermonRow(it.title, it.timestamp)
        Divider(thickness = 1.dp, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp))
                }

        }

    }
```

---

```
**Data.kt**


   val kbfList = listOf<Kbf>(
        Kbf(
            title = "The Purpose Of KBF", description = "", imageId = R.drawable.kbf_tony, sermons = 
listOf<Sermon>(
            Sermon(title= "The Purpose Of KBF", image= "kbf_tony", url= 
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/O5xZCZlCqBw", timestamp= "1612674000"),
        )),
    Kbf(
        title = "Goal Setting", description = "", imageId = R.drawable.kbf_mike, sermons = 
listOf<Sermon>(
            Sermon(title = "Goal Setting", image = "kbf_mike", url = 
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/HRDPWpUagxY", timestamp = "1612674000")
            ))
    )
```

[image: Play-url Button]

Comment: just pass the full `Sermon` object and u can access the url string too

Comment: @Santanu Sur  Thanks for the response, for some reason it's not opening the url when clicked.